# Beamer and graphic accent

Tags: beamer, accents

I am using the beamer class for my thesis in Italian. Written Italian includes graphic accents, but beamer misunderstand them. This is a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    Test: à 
\end{document}
```

All I get is an 'A' with a '~' symbol on top.

Comment: Have you saved in Latin-1 encoding? It works for me if you do, but fails as you describe when saved in UTF-8.

Comment: where can I choose how to save file?

Comment: That depends on which editor you use.

Comment: TexMaker: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way I found to put accented letters and ensure multiuser and multisystem compatibility is to encode the document in UTF8.

If you use texmaker Preferences -> Editor -> Font Encoding. Select UTF8.

Then in the document preamble write:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: I'm italian too, and I remember the pains when I started using LaTeX :)

Comment: Does it work for  Σ ⇛ ⇒ too ?

Comment: Yes, it works for every UTF-8 character. But this is LaTeX, you have macros for those characters in the math environment. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try a semi-automatic input selection by the [selinput](http://ctan.org/pkg/selinput) package from the [oberdiek](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) bundle.

```
\documentclass[italian]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}     % Replacement for »inputenc«
\SelectInputMappings{     % Semi-automatic input selection
  agrave={à},             % by a list of selected glyphs
  egrave={è},             % see: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/opentype/glyphlist.txt
  Euro={€}
}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Test: à ì
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```