# MikTex doesn't accept "ù" character

Tags: miktex, accents, characters

I'm using MikTex and pdfLatex. In the preamble I'm using

```
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

because I'm writing in italian, and the text is coded in UTF-8.

This works nicely for every type of accented char [à,è,é,ì,ò] except than ù.
Whenever I try to output a pdf I receive the well-known $ missing error if there's a "ù" around. What can I do?

Error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.56 ...filo Twitter @MiurSocial non pubblica più
                                                   da aprile 2012,
```

I'm pretty sure there are no underscores or other special chars, and this happens only with ùs.

Thanks!

EDIT: if i use utf8 instead of latin1 I get this:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:� not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 ...abbreviazione di electronic government, �
                                                   l'insieme di tutte le pr
```

---

code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm,textheight=21cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\graphicspath{ {immagini/} }
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[CE]{\bfseries\leftmark} %C = center O= odd  E=even
\fancyhead[CO]{\bfseries\rightmark} %C = center O= odd  E=even
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcommand{\miur}{Ministero Italiano dell' Università e della ricerca}
\begin{document}
\input{cap1.tex}
\input{cap2.tex}
\input{cap3.tex}
\input{cap4.tex}
\input{cap5.tex}
\end{document}
```

The text giving problems has been directly input from keyboard and it's encoded in UTF-8. Now I tried with encoding it as ISO-8859-1 and it works.

Comment: Try to use `utf8` instead of `latin1`.

Comment: So, I guess that you copied this part of text from somewhere. Try to delete this character and type it directly using your keyboard.

Comment: No, I didn't... this is the strange part. I'm inputting the ù directly from the keyboard.

Comment: So, please, try to put here a simple complete code showing the problem. Maybe you are loading some other fonts or packages. Are you using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: We can not compile with `input` since we don't have your `tex` files. But this is not a problem. We can comment it. Well, I don1t have `svg` package and so I removed it. Now, everything is fine here.

Comment: >    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
> 
> because I'm writing in italian, and the text is coded in UTF-8.
> 
> This works nicely for every type of accented char [à,è,é,ì,ò] except than ù.

No if that worked then your existing document is encoded in latin1 (iso-8859-1) not UTF-8.
The declared encoding has to match the actual encoding, or you get an error.

Comment: I was about to say the same as @DavidCarlisle, I believe you have saved your document in the wrong encoding.  Try making sure you have used UTF8

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "This works nicely for every type of accented char [à,è,é,ì,ò] except than ù." Does it work for ó?

Comment: Perhaps [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54295/beamer-and-italian-accented-letters/54300#54300) to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54295) helps.

Comment: I can't believe in 2016 we are still dealing with such awful mess